# Is it possible to work in France with German residence permit? I am Ukraininan

Tags: germany, france

I am Ukrainian and will study in France for one semester as a student in an Erasmus+ program. My home university is in Germany, and I have a German residence permit due to my studies.

Unfortunately, my application to work from abroad was rejected by my company, and my boss didn't renew my contract. I am worried about my income and hope to be able to work in France. However, I am pretty sure it's not possible with a German residence permit.

Does anyone have any information about if it's forbidden?

Maybe there is any way to get around this? Maybe there are some services where I can find a job like walking the dog for money? I don't think I need a permit for this kind of work.

And if I need a French visa for this - can I get one in France upon arrival?

Comment: Paid work is paid work, a work permit is generally required no matter what type of work it is. What did the French university say when you asked them about the rules pertaining to working while studying on an Erasmus+ programme?

Comment: You should ask your university since you will be going to France based on the **Erasmus+ program**.

Comment: @JonathanReez Participatation in the **Erasmus+ program** goes throught the university, which includes any required permits for 3rd country nationals.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's terrible advice. In my experience, universities already struggle to give competent advice regarding legal issues in their own countries. There is exactly 0 chance a German university will have any idea about what's allowed in France and I don't have high hopes that the French university's international relation office could offer any help.

Comment: @Relaxed [Erasmus+: Requirements regarding visa and residence permits](https://erasmus-plus.ec.europa.eu/programme-guide/part-a/eligible-countries): *Participants in Erasmus+ projects may need to obtain a visa for staying abroad in the EU Member States and third countries associated to the Programme or third country not associated to the Programme hosting the activity. **It is a responsibility of all the participating organisations to ensure that the authorisations required (short or long-term stay visas or residence permits) are in order before the planned activity takes place**.*

Comment: @MarkJohnson The question is not about staying and studying but about working while doing it so your quote is completely irrelevant. I agree that the host university *should* be able to help for basic questions relative to entry and stay but even there my experience is that you frequently get useless or misleading advice so I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 4):

According to the French public service website, you will need a temporary work authorisation before undertaking any paid activity, this request can be done online either by you or your new employer.

Sources:

- Can I work as a student in France Questionnaire (I selected the following options: "I am not algerian" and "I will study in France for one semester"): https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2713/personnalisation/resultat?lang=&quest0=1&quest1=3&quest=

Comment: (+1) Legally, only the employer can apply for that “authorisation”. If the employee submits the application online, they need the employer to provide a paper giving them permission to apply on the employer's behalf (“mandat“).

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have any information about if it's forbidden?

It's not exactly forbidden but as a third-country citizen, you need some authorisation to work in France. Your German residence permit is not enough for that so you need something else.

> Maybe there is any way to get around this? Maybe there are some services where I can find a job like walking the dog for money? I don't think I need a permit for this kind of work.

That's incorrect, you need a permit or authorisation in any case. Theoretically, even working remotely for your German employer would have required one. French residence permits for students do allow some incidental work (especially internships) but this wouldn't apply to you as you have a German residence permit.

> And if I need a French visa for this - can I get one in France upon arrival?

You cannot get a long-stay visa in France. If you do need one, you need to get it before entering, that's the whole point of the procedure. But since it seems you already have the right to stay in France, you don't need a visa, you only need a work authorisation (the procedure mentioned by @meego). This authorisation is specific to an employer so you need to find one that would be interested in hiring you before applying.